# Most efficient way of updating ~100 million rows in Postgresql database?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, bigdata, crud

I have a database with a single table. This table will need to be updated every few weeks. We need to ingest third-party data into it and it will contain 100-120 million rows. So the flow is basically:

1. Get the raw data from the source
2. Detect inserts, updates & deletes
3. Make updates and ingest into the database

What's the best way of detecting and performing updates?
Some options are:

1. Compare incoming data with current database one by one and make single updates. This seems very slow and not feasible.
2. Ingest incoming data into a new table, then switch out old table with the new table
3. Bulk updates in-place in the current table. Not sure how to do this.

What do you suggest is the best option, or if there's a different option out there?

Comment: For moving large amounts of data into Postgres the quickest way is [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html). `COPY` the data into a staging table and either do your table switch or do `INSERT INTO`/`UPDATE/DELETE` using joins between the staging table and permanent  table.

Comment: If you can use table partitioning and update an entire partition in one step, that might speed up things as well. The whole proces is also highly dependent on the available IO and maybe CPU as well.

Comment: What are you trying to optimize for?  Run time, WAL generation, probability of mistakes, downtime, etc.?  What indexes or foreign keys do you have?

Answer (score 7):

Postgres has a helpful guide for improving performance of [bulk loads](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/populate.html). From your description, you need to perform a bulk  `INSERT` in addition to a bulk `UPDATE` and `DELETE`. Below is a roughly step by step guide for making this efficient:

##### Configure Global Database Configuration Variables Before the Operation

```sql
ALTER SYSTEM SET max_wal_size = <size>;
```

You can additionally disable WAL entirely.

```sql
ALTER SYSTEM SET wal_level = 'minimal';
ALTER SYSTEM SET archive_mode = 'off';
ALTER SYSTEM SET max_wal_senders = 0;
```

Note that these changes will require a database restart to take effect.

##### Start a Transaction

You want all work to be done in a single transaction in case anything goes wrong. Running COPY in parallel across multiple connections does not usually increase performance as disk is usually the limiting factor.

##### Optimize Other Configuration Variables at the Transaction level

```sql
SET LOCAL maintenance_work_mem = <size>
...
```

You may need to set other configuration parameters if you are doing any additional special processing of the data inside Postgres (`work_mem` is usually most important there especially if using Postgis extension.) See [this guide](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server) for the most important configuration variables for performance.

##### `CREATE` a `TEMPORARY` table with no constraints.

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE changes(
  id bigint,
  data text,
) ON COMMIT DROP; --ensures this table will be dropped at end of transaction
```

##### Bulk Insert Into `changes` using `COPY FROM`

Use the [`COPY FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) Command to bulk insert the raw data into the temporary table.

```sql
COPY changes(id,data) FROM ..
```

##### `DROP` Relations That Can Slow Processing

On the `target` table, `DROP` all foreign key constraints, indexes and triggers (where possible). Don't drop your PRIMARY KEY, as you'll want that for the `INSERT`.

#### Add a Tracking Column to `target` Table

Add a column to `target` table to determine if row was present in changes table:

```sql
ALTER TABLE target ADD COLUMN seen boolean;
```

##### UPSERT from the `changes` table into the `target` table:

UPSERTs are performed by adding an `ON CONFLICT` clause to a standard `INSERT` statement. This prevents the need from performing two separate operations.

```sql
INSERT INTO target(id,data,seen) 
  SELECT 
    id,
    data,
    true
  FROM
    changes
  ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET data = EXCLUDED.data, seen = true;
```

##### `DELETE` Rows Not In `changes` Table

```sql
DELETE FROM target WHERE not seen is true;
```

##### `DROP` Tracking Column and Temporary `changes` Table

```sql
DROP TABLE changes;
ALTER TABLE target DROP COLUMN seen;
```

##### Add Back Relations You Dropped For Performance

Add back all constraints, triggers and indexes that were dropped to improve bulk upsert performance.

##### Commit Transaction

The bulk upsert/delete is complete and the following commands should be performed outside of a transaction.

##### Run `VACUUM ANALYZE` on the `target` Table.

This will allow the query planner to make appropriate inferences about the table and reclaim space taken up by dead tuples.

```sql
SET maintenance_work_mem = <size>
VACUUM ANALYZE target;
SET maintenance_work_mem = <original size>
```

##### Restore Original Values of Database Configuration Variables

```sql
ALTER SYSTEM SET max_wal_size = <size>;
...
```

You may need to restart your database again for these settings to take effect.