# How to update billions row in a Database in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

We have to use a null column to Hardcoded Value 'Yes'. Can't use simple script

```
update my_table
set column='Yes'
where column is Null
```

Since we have huge chucks of data, this isn't the way. What is the best way to update it?

Comment: Why are you using text instead of a `boolean`-typed column?

Comment: We have to use text only because in in future we have to update some rows into long text.

Comment: What relevance is it to tag `mysql` here?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72636315/most-efficient-way-of-updating-100-million-rows-in-postgresql-database

Comment: @RavikantPandey that doesn't make the current design a good one - if you want to store multiple options, use a lookup table and store its PK values. Storing freeform text just begs for bugs. There's no other way to update rows than UPDATE either. What's the actual purpose of that column? Perhaps a redesign would eliminate the problem. Perhaps there's no need to change the value, unless you really want to change from Unknown to a specific value. Perhaps you need to batch the updates, executing eg 1000 at a time

Comment: Solution in duplicate applies to billions of rows too.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of updating billions of rows with only field as "Yes" for every record, I would suggest you to create another lookup table and add record in it only when source record has other than `"Yes"` using your Primary Key from Original Table with new Lookup table.

```
//create table lookupTable;
CREATE TABLE lookUpTable (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    recordFor INT NOT NULL, //Your my_table record id 
    myText varchar(10) NOT NULL
);
```

Search this table against your `my_table` row. If the record is found in `LookupTable` than `myText` value otherwise false.